given a sql query, how to know the data contribution from each table
I have iceberg tables on aws.
i am trying to use Athena or presto to query them.
My question is: how to know the data contribution from each table to the result.
e.g. How to know how many rows in the result are from table A and table B?
(select * from table A where XXX)
union
(select * from table B where YYY)

As for Athena, I am trying to use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/get-query-runtime-statistics.html, but it seems that there are no what i want.
it is possible to get the information from presto query metadata?
Any comments welcomed.
Thanks

Can you please elaborate? Or add some sample data and desired output?

There is no direct method to know this. You can use count to know this. The below way to adjust query.
SELECT 
    'table_a' AS source_table,
    COUNT(*) AS contribution_count
FROM 
    table_a a
LEFT JOIN 
    table_b b 
ON 
    a.common_key = b.common_key
GROUP BY 
    source_table
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'table_b' AS source_table,
    COUNT(*) AS contribution_count
FROM 
    table_b b
LEFT JOIN 
    table_a a 
ON 
    b.common_key = a.common_key
GROUP BY 
    source_table;

